# Correlation between localisation & local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$, then one can define the localisation $S^{-1}R$ of $R$ at $S$. Now if $p$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and we set $S=R\setminus p$ then $S$ is multiplicative and $S^{-1}R$ is a local ring (only maximal ideal is $m=\{(a,s)\in S^{-1}R \mid a\in p, s\in S\}$).

My question: Is $S^{-1}R$ a local ring if and only if $S=R\setminus p$ for some prime ideal $p$ of $R$? Or are there $S$ such that $S^{-1}R$ is local where $S$ is not necessarily of the form $S=R\setminus p$?

I am trying to figure out what local rings in this environment look like.

Comment: The maximal ideals of $S^{-1}R$ correspond bijectively to the ideals of $R$ maximal among those disjoint from $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal. Let $S = 1 + \mathfrak{p}$. Then $S^{-1} R$ is a local ring; the same one you'd get if you used $R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ instead.

Proof: For any $a \in R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, $a$ is a unit in the field $R / \mathfrak{p}$. So there exists a $b$ such that $ab \in S$, and therefore $1/a = b/(ab)$ is in $S^{-1} R$.

---

Let $S$ be the set of all things of the form $a^2$ for $a \in R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Then again $S^{-1} R$ is the localization of $R$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, since if $a \in R \setminus{\mathfrak{p}}$, then $1/a = a/a^2$.

---

In general, $S$ doesn't need to contain *everything* you need to invert, just "enough" of them.

Comment: For your two examples there exists $S$ of form $S=R\setminus p$ for some prime ideal $p$. Does that mean: yes, if $S^{-1}R$ is local then $S=R\setminus p$ for some prime ideal $p$ ?

Comment: Why does $S$ have this form?

Comment: @Thomas: Did you mean to ask "If $S^{-1} R$ is a local ring, then does there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $S^{-1} R = T^{-1} R$ where $T = R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$?" If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, thanks!